# Virtuoso inferencing support for similar queries. (SPARQL FILTER FUNCTION)

Tags: sparql, inference, virtuoso

I build a tool for skos taxonomies with a virtuoso triple store in the background.
I noticed that some query versions do not return inferenced results.

For example having only the following Triple in your Triple Strore:

```
<http://someExample/Parent> skos:narrower <http://someExample/Child>.
```

Then when using the following query I will get the expected result <http://someExample/Parent>. As narrower and broader are defined as inverse properties:

```
 DEFINE input:inference 'skos:rules' #skos definitions for inferencing
 SELECT DISTINCT ?concept
 where
 {
     <http://someExample/Child> skos:broader ?concept.
 }
```

But when using the following query, inferenced results are not returned :

```
 DEFINE input:inference 'skos:rules' 
 SELECT DISTINCT ?property ?concept
 where
 {
      <http://someExample/Child> ?property ?concept.
      FILTER(?property = skos:broader)
 }
```

As I read in the virtuoso documentation, the inferenced triples are "created" when queried. I can imagine that virtuoso does not support this type of query for some reason but I am not experienced in this whole RDF world. So, is there any possibility to construct queries with the FILTER funciton which return inferenced triples as well, or is it just not supported?

Comment: At a quick glance, I don't see what would cause your experience. I suggest you raise this Virtuoso-specific question to a more Virtuoso-focused forum, either as an [issue on the github project](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/), or as a post on the [OpenLink Community Forum](https://community.openlinksw.com/). Please include the specific version of your Virtuoso binary, and include a link to the SPARQL endpoint, if it's publicly accessible.